# Count elements in an excel column with python

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python. I have an excel document with one first column with with several elements (Column 1 with "a" and "b") and a second column with values for the elements in column 1:

```
Column 1  Column 2
   a        10
   a        100
   b        1
   b        15
   b        10
```

I'm trying to write an script in Python 3 in which I get the following:

```
Column 1  Column 2
   a        110     --> Sum of all elements in previous column 1 for a
   b        26      --> Sum of all elements in previous column 1 for b
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

I already tried with lists and dictionaries but I'm not getting a reasonable answer.

```
Column 1  Column 2
   a        110     --> Sum of all elements in previous column 1 for a
   b        26      --> Sum of all elements in previous column 1 for b
```

```
from xlwt import Workbook
i=0
for element in Column_1:
    sheet1.write(i,0,element)
    i +=1
```

Comment: Try to read excel file into ```pandas``` to start with, and please share the code, what you already tried

Comment: Please share the python code, how you used it. We need to have something to work with ;)